# Two phase construction to use shared_from_this() during object creation for derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a setup with a base class that inherits from enable_shared_from_this

```
class Object : public enable_shared_from_this<Object>
{ ... };
```

I inherit from enable_shared_from_this because I need to call shared_from_this() every so often. In certain derivations of Object, I need to call shared_from_this() from with in the constructor, which can't be done:

```
class Thing : public Object
{
public:
    Thing() : Object(...) 
    { doSomething(shared_from_this()); /* error */ }
};
```

So a work around is two-phase construction.

```
class Thing : public Object
{
public:
    Thing() : Object(...) {  }
    void Init() { /* safe to call shared_from_this here */ }
};
```

A valid way to create a Thing object would be:

```
shared_ptr<Thing> thing = make_shared<Thing>();
thing->Init();
```

This is not very nice and error prone but at least it works. However, now there's an issue with further inheritance:

```
class Bling : public Thing
{
public:
    Bling() : Thing(...) { ... }
    void Init() { /* safe to call shared_from_this here */ }
};

// How do we create a Bling object?
shared_ptr<Bling> bling = make_shared<Bling>();
static_cast<Thing*>(bling.get())->Init(); // horrible
bling->Init();

// Maybe Bling::Init should look like:
// Bling::Init() { Thing::Init(); /* + other stuff */ }
// then we could do:
shared_ptr<Bling> bling = make_shared<Bling>();
bling->Init(); // etc
```

Is there a safer or cleaner way to do this? For example, API wise its less error prone to make the constructors for Object, Thing and Bling private and use a static Init() function that creates the shared_ptr:

```
static shared_ptr<Bling> Bling::Init() {
    auto bling = make_shared<Bling>();
    Bling::init(bling);
    return bling;
}

static void Bling::init(shared_ptr<Bling> bling) {
    /* chain parent class init */
    Thing::init(bling); // sig: Thing::init(shared_ptr<Thing>);

    /* do init stuff */
}

// calls Object(), Thing(), Bling(), 
// Object::init(), Thing::init(), Bling::init()
auto bling = Bling::Init();
```

Basically I'm looking for patterns to implement object creation in a way where I can use a shared_ptr to the object during creation. I need to allow for basic inheritance. I would like suggested methods to consider end-user ease of use and developer maintainability.

Comment: Sounds like a natural application for a factory pattern which has the nice side-effect of forcing the construction of a shared pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not rely on the fact that the user of an object initially always holds it in a shared pointer. Design the class such that objects are allowed on the stack and heap.

How to solve this depends on what you do with the pointer returned by `shared_from_this()`.

The one thing that comes to my mind is that the object registers itself somewhere - i.e. outside of the object. In my opinion it is better to do that outside of the data classes derived from `Object`. If you have a registry object of class `Registry`, turn it into a factory (as suggested by David Schwartz):

```c++11
class Registry;

class Object
{
protected:
    Object() = default;
    friend Registry;
public:
    // ...
};

class Thing : public Object
{
protected:
    Thing() = default;
    friend Registry;
public:
    // ...
};

class Registry
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Object>> store;
public:
    shared_ptr<Thing> CreateThing()
    {
        shared_ptr<Thing> newThing = make_shared<Thing>();
        newThing->init(); // If you like.
        store.push_back(newThing);
        return newThing;
    }
    shared_ptr<Bling> CreateBling();
    // ...
};
```

- No need for `enable_shared_from_this` at all.
- Easier to understand.
- Responsibilities clear.
- Easily changed such that unregistered `Object` and `Thing` objects are allowed. (Scratch the protected constructor and the `friend` declaration.)

It might already be clear, but just to be sure: I am not in favor of `enable_shared_from_this`. It makes the assumption, that the object is managed by a `shared_ptr` at the time `shared_from_this()` is called. If this is not the case, the "behavior is undefined". If at least it would be an exception or `nullptr` would be returned...

Such assumptions are ok, when the creation of the initial `shared_ptr` and the call of `shared_from_this()` are close to each other in the code (whatever that means). Does anyone have a use case for this? I don`t.