# Add a Child to its Parent from the constructor

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm trying to create a child class that can add itself to the parent's vector from its own constructor, but the problem is that i can't use `enable_shared_from_this` and `shared_from_this()` according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) :

> It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr (in particular, shared_from_this cannot be called during construction of *this).

```
class Parent
{

public:

Parent(){}

void addChild(const std::shared_ptr<Child>& child)
{
    _childs.push_back(child);
}

private:

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Child>> _childs;

};

class Child
{

public:

    Child(const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& parent)
    {
        parent->addChild(...); // Here the problem
    }
}


int main()
{
    auto parent = std::make_shared<Parent>();
    auto child = std::make_shared<Child>(parent);

    return 0;
}
```

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712865/two-phase-construction-to-use-shared-from-this-during-object-creation-for-deri) but it does not answer my problem, I want to be able to add the child class to the parent class only from the constructor without having to go through another function after. Is it possible ?

Comment: `std::make_shared<Child>(parent)` roughly does `auto p = new Child(parent); shared_ptr<Child> sp(p); return sp;`. At the time `Child` constructor runs, the `shared_ptr` instance doesn't exist yet, so there's nothing to pass along to `Parent`. You'll have to reconsider your design, I don't think what you currently have can be salvaged.

Comment: What's the lifetime relationship between parent and child? Does the parent own its children? Or does one of them outlive the other?

Comment: @JonathanS. i'm just looking for a way to reduce the code usage by following this structure `auto child = std::make_shared<Child>(parent);` without having to write something after to add the child to its parent !

Comment: Does the parent need a `shared_ptr`? If the destructor of the `Child` removes the pointer from the parent again, it could be a non-owning pointer there? Or does the `shared_ptr` created otherwise go out of scope and the child would get destroyed prematurely?

Comment: @Sebastian I'm using class forward declaration, so i don't think i have much choice

Comment: What about using explicit pointers rather than this `shared_ptr` syntax ? To be honest I don't know this new specification and this is very confusing to me...

Comment: Could you answer Jonathan's question in more detail, please?

Comment: @Sebastian The parent controls the lifetime of its children present in the vector, it's a one-sided relationship, the only need of the parent for child is during creation to add itself to the vector !

Comment: In that case, why don't you give the parent class a templated factory member function that constructs a child and adds it? That way you can also use ```std::unique_ptr``` in your vector and save yourself some headaches. I.e. ```parent->createChild<ChildType>(...);```

Comment: Sorry if my remark is stupid, but does `parent->addChild(this);` could not solve the problem ?

Comment: @Sedenion your remark is not stupid, I tested it but I don't know why it doesn't work!

Comment: @JonathanS. Yes, this is the only solution I have at the moment

Comment: @AlTilmidh ok, what I am pretty sure about, is that all this would work using explicit pointers with `new` keyword instead of smart_ptr, auto and such things. But I guess your question is for this way to do and not the "old" one.

Comment: Raw pointers are still the new way, but only as non-owning pointers. As you want to have parent *own* the pointers, you need a factory function (not necessarily in parent, but this `createChild`, see Jonathan's post, would be a good option). Important is that the factory function does make_unique (preferred over `make_shared` as `unique_ptr` has clearer ownership semantics, clearer lifetime and is more performant on top).

Comment: You could change `addChild` in parent to accept a raw pointer and create a `unique_ptr` in the parent. addChild would then be called by the constructor. But then: 1) The unique smart pointer is created late and until then you have the danger of exceptions and memory leaks, 2) The constructor of the child would act like a normal constructor and return a pointer and at the same time it would register an owning pointer with parent. This is unexpected and could lead with wrong usage to two owning pointers. Danger of double `delete`.

Comment: 3) You do not know the allocator used, when within child's constructor. Creating a smart pointer there instead of at the callsite of the constructor could lead to deleting local instances of child, which were created on the stack and not on the heap.

Comment: => For those 3 reasons, a factor method within parent or the child or a free function or a 3rd class should be preferred over trying it to do in the constructor alone. E.g. you could create a static factory function within child, which returns a `unique_ptr`. See it as a special constructor. Or better use the factory `createChild` in parent, as you always register the child instances with parent.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

```
struct Best : std::enable_shared_from_this<Best> // note: public inheritance
{
    std::shared_ptr<Best> getptr() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    // No public constructor, only a factory function,
    // so there's no way to have getptr return nullptr.
    [[nodiscard]] static std::shared_ptr<Best> create() {
        // Not using std::make_shared<Best> because the c'tor is private.
        return std::shared_ptr<Best>(new Best());
    }
private:
    Best() = default;
};
```

You just make the constructor private and use static method `create` with arguments you need.

---

So after you inherit `std::enable_shared_from_this<Child>` your main function will be:

```
auto parent = std::make_shared<Parent>();
auto child = Child::create(parent);
```

And you would be able to safely pass `std::shared_ptr<Child>` to `Parent` in `Child::create`:

```
[[nodiscard]] static std::shared_ptr<Child> create(std::shared_ptr<Parent> parent) {
        // Not using std::make_shared<Best> because the c'tor is private.
        auto child = std::shared_ptr<Child>(new Child())
        parent->addChild(child);
        return child;
    }
```

I beleive using its own factory function is approriate.
When you need to customize `Child` creation:

- add parameters to constructor
- change the logic of creation
  you will not need to change the `Parent` class.

This is more SRP-friendly than forsing a `Parent` to create a child.

Comment: *It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr<T>. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17) or std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17).* With this answer you cannot get a shared pointer within the constructor.

Comment: Okay! The create function in the first code block is without parameters unlike the ones below. Also the OP should think about the many uses of `shared_ptr`, which muddy ownership relations.

Comment: @Sebastian personally I don't think `shared_ptr` should be used in the first place unless it is necessary by design. But I answer the question in regards to "initialization code".

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible I believe because `make_shared` will first allocate the child and only after complete the `shared_ptr`. Plus there is no way to get the address of the `shared_ptr` in the child constructor.

I think what you have to do is change your `addChild` method:

```
std::shared_ptr<Child> addChild() {
   _childs.push_back(std::make_shared<Child>());
   return _childs.back();
}

auto parent = std::make_shared<Parent>();
auto child = parent->addChild();
```

You can keep the `void` if you want, this is just to keep more in line with your existing code.

PS: the plural of child is children.